# Javascript calculate / update total onclick multiple form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im helping a friend building a basic site. My javascript skills leaves much to be desired so I am learning I started with Javascript instead of Jquery library (sidenote: should I just go with Jquery from the start...?)

So I have the following:

- Form with 3 radio buttons value low(1), medium(2), high(3)
- Slider with amount
- Select with duration.

The formula is calculated by user selecting risk (radio btns) amount (slider) duration (dropdowm)

When the user changes risk, or amount, or duration the total should get updated, and a button displayed.

[image]

So I came up with the following javascript:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function getReturn(){
    var risk = document.forms[0];
    var years = document.getElementById("investmentDuration").value;
    var slideAmount  = document.getElementById("slideAmount").value;
    var txt;
    var returns;
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < risk.length; i++){
        if(risk[i].checked){
            txt = risk[i].value;
            //for
            if(txt == 1){
                returns = (slideAmount * 0.06)*years;
                returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals

            }
            if(txt == 2){
                returns = slideAmount  * 0.11;
                returns = Math.ceil(returns)*years; // NO decimals

            }
            if(txt == 3){
                returns = slideAmount *0.17;
                returns = Math.ceil(returns)*years; // NO decimals
            }
        }//if
    }//for
```

I then added the `getReturn()` function to each element in the form...

I get the following when I try and run it, [here is my JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisChros/o1zmvmL9/)

**ERROR:** `getReturn() is not defined`

**HTML** (note the on click function on each element)

```
 <h2>SELECT INVESTMENT RISK LEVEL</h2>
    <section>
        <div>
           <input type="radio"  id="control_01" onclick="getReturn()" name="risk" value="1" checked>
            <label for="control_01">
                <h2>LOW RISK</h2>
                <p>Slow & Steady. An Product Focused On Low Risk But Long term Gains</p>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="control_02" name="risk" onclick="getReturn()" value="2">
            <label for="control_02">
                <h2>MEDIUM</h2>
                <p>Prepare For Glory. Medium To High Returns, Over A Medium To Long Period.</p>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="control_03" name="risk" onclick="getReturn()" value="3">
            <label for="control_03">
                <h2>High Risk</h2>
                <p>Hardcore Investor. Tailored Based Package Focused on High Returns Over Short Periods</p>
            </label>
        </div>
    </section>

 <h4 style="color: black;">INVESTMENT AMOUNT:</h4>
        <input type="range" id="slideAmount" name="slideAmount" onchange="getReturn()" value="6500" step="25" min="1000" max="10000">

  <p>Number Of Years</p>
            <select  name="investmentDuration" id="investmentDuration" onclick="getReturn()">
                <option value="1" selected>1 Year</option>
                <option value="2">2 Years</option>
                <option value="3">3 Years</option>
                <option value="4">4 Years</option>
                <option value="5">5 Years</option>
            </select>
```

**UPDATE**

I got it to work however I feel

1. Having a `onclick() / onchange = function()` on each element seems inefficient.
2. I feel the code is prone to bugs if the page should get larger and expanded on.

Any constructive criticism and / or advice appreciated on how I can work and improve on this. Many Thanks

Comment: 1. Too much waffle to read ;) 2. Fix your console errors `document.getElementById("regFormMsg").innerHTML` and not `document.getElementById("returns").innerHTML` 3. The fiddle settings need to be `in head` not `onload`

Comment: `returns = (slideAmount * [0,0.06,0.11,0.17][risk[i].value])*years;`

Comment: Also use `onchange` instead of `onclick` and have a `please select` in the duration

Comment: @mplungjan come on mate its not that bad, not all that much waffle ;) trying my best here

Comment: I started editing it for content but the code was so entrenched in waffle I gave up ;) ;) - no offense, just give us the beef and not the life story - the code is not horrible but a proper [mcve] had the issues become visible. My second comment is just a suggestion to shorten the code

Comment: @mplungjan noted and thank you, just thought the more info the better but will keep in mind for future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the

> `getReturn()` is not defined

error because your code is inside an `onLoad` event (*that is the default in jsfiddle*)

You need to change this setting as shown in the image so that your function is in the global scope and thus callable from the DOM.

[image]

Then you also need to add the `#returns` element in your html.

A final improvement might be to use the oninput event on the range element so that is updates while you slide

All fixes: https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/o1zmvmL9/2/

Comment: @Gaby Thanks for that yeah it was strange it worked in my browser but not JSFiddle. Could you please tell me if it is bad practice having `onclick='getReturns()'` on each element...not really sure how else I can continually update the amount if that makes sense...?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee you could use the `oninput` event and apply it on the whole `form` element (*as the event bubbles*), this way you only need it once and it will handle any additional modifiers you might add in the future. See https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/o1zmvmL9/3/

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thank you for the help...had a look at your code and fiddle, works well only problem is total does not update when radio buttons are clicked...

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee seems that the `oninput` only works with radio buttons in firefox. Better use the `onchange`. (*or both if you want the while-sliding to also work*)